# Accidentally compiled my c file into [readonly][noeol][converted] in Ubuntu Vim

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, vim

I am a new programer and while trying to compile my .c file in the Ubuntu terminal I accidentally wrote:

```
gcc -o file.c file -Wall
```

Instead of:

```
gcc -o file file.c -Wall
```

Now I have a file marked as [readonly][noeol][converted] in vim and I wanted to know how can I revert this to my normal file.c?

Edit: To clarify, the error I got while compiling was:

> /usr/bin/ld: file: stderr: invalid version 2 (max 0)
> /usr/bin/ld: file: error adding symbols: bad value
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Is this question really about gcc? Aren't you rather asking where to find backup files of the source in Vim?

Comment: Sorry for bad news, but if file flags have been modified the output file itself is most likely overwritten, too – so it is lost anyway. If you don't have a backup of elsewhere you likely need to rewrite it.

Comment: To avoid problems I would suggest installing eclipse CDT and focusing on programming, not on toolchains, program locations, configurations and command-line options

Comment: On technique, just before every progress mod I make, I drag and drop the file to say  `file - Copy (4).c` and I end up the dozens of historic stage progess files. Eventually I clean up and keep one good one with a version number in the file name, say file-100.c along with annotation as to what it does.

Comment: heh, I've done the same thing before <facepalm>. I got out of the habit of using the `-o` option. `a.out` works for me, especially during development. Simply rename to something more descriptive when  you're done. Even better, learn how to use a build system like make or CMake, and a version control system like git. Probably overkill for whatever you're working on now, but it would certainly prevent problems like this, allow you to recover your source if you did happen to overwrite, and pay dividends in the future gaining experience with industry tools.

Comment: Generalising @0___________ 's recommendation: At least use *any* IDE – there's a bunch of more or less good ones out there, code::blocks, netbeans, and many others – with eclipse actually being my personal preference as well (and Microsoft products not being on my *personal* recommendation list...).

Comment: Compile using `make file` at the command line.  The `make` program doesn't make that sort of mistake.

Comment: You probably have no easy way of restoring the file sadly.
However, to avoid such mistakes in the futures, two things you could do is: 1. use makefiles 2. use git to track your code. There's absolutely nothing wrong with using the command line to compile stuff, it just takes a little time to get used to it.